# How to mount 3 ISO images as repos in SLES using zypper

Tags: linux, mount, iso-image, zypper

I'm wanting to mount the three ISO disks of the SLES11SP3 OS onto my system, as we have a minimal installation and we need to zypper install some additional packages.

```
zypper addrepo iso:/?iso=/path/to/iso1.iso disk1
zypper addrepo iso:/?iso=/path/to/iso2.iso disk2
zypper addrepo iso:/?iso=/path/to/iso3.iso disk3
```

However for the second disk, although I add it successfully, the zypper update disables the second disk because:

```
zypper update
File '/media.1/media' not found on medium 'iso:///?iso=/path/to/disk/SUSE11SP3_002.iso'
```

Now the disk is correct -> /media.2/media is the file that exists on the other disk, as it should by this post:
https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Sta...ia_description
so given it's the second disk, the directory should be /media.2 as the numeral is the disk number.
Here's another question on another forum also unanswered:
https://forums.suse.com/archive/index.php/t-1507.html

I think I might need to indicate to zypper to "expect" the disk as #2 but no flag in the zypper man pages seem be useful.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately SUSE Enterprise Linux is not too rigorously tested and this definitely escaped testing. What you will need to do is extract the ISO to a folder, and add the folder to the repo list (either with YaSt or zypper, using  `dir:///path/to/extracted_ISO`) and rename `media.2` to `media.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Disk3 was actually Disk1b -> a part of the first ISO
adding them as disk1, disk3 then disk2 worked.